# Define a separate css-file for an included php-file?

Tags: php, css

I have a basic website layout and I've managed to get the show_news.php (using Cutenews) to display inside one of the divs.  My problem might just be that I'm not really familiar with php (yet), but here's what happens:

The show_news.php gets the css formatting from the css for the actual page and not the default.css (under cutenews/skins). How can I define the show_news.php to use the skins/default.css -file? If I'd use iframes it would work out of the box, but I guess the problem is that the show_news.php has been implemented on the page/inside the div like this:

```
<?php include ("cutenews/show_news.php"); ?>
```

Am I completely lost here or what?

Comment: which is the `actual page`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it might be solved using only CSS selectors.

If your container has let's say id="show_news_container"
then adding to your CSS stylesheet #show_news_container in right places might be your solution

Comment: Thank you :) It was dead simple!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have separate css file for files included by PHP.

Either include css definitions globally (`<style>` or `<link>` tag in your 'actual' page), or have them defined inline (with `<style>` tag) in show_news.php.